# Error with some Image using Raster.getPixel

Tags: java, bufferedimage

i ran into the problem yesterday using the BufferedImage Lib, i get a

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

but only for pictures "PNG" i get from the net, but if i make my own in Paint it all works. i have tryed looking up the problem but cant see where im wrong.

```
package grayandconvert;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class JavaCodeProject { // remain if needed Kim
   private final String PATH = "C:\\New folder\\"; //
   private final String graypath = PATH + "oZPX0bbg.png"; // filename for Grayscale pic
   private final String imgpath = PATH + "oZPX0bb.png";      // filename for Orginal pic 
   private final String textpath =PATH + "filename.txt";   // filename for Output textfile
   private final String imgtype = "png";                    // image file type for Grascale "png" "jpg"


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JavaCodeProject main = new JavaCodeProject();  //new class for use of the metoth
        main.grayscale();
        main.convert();


    }


    public void convert()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedImage image =ImageIO.read(new File(graypath)); // called the gray pic for image
            int[] pixel;                                // int array named pixel
            System.out.print(image.getHeight());
            System.out.print(image.getWidth());
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) // outer forloop to control Y axel image.getWidth
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) //inner forloop to control X axel
                {
                    pixel = image.getRaster().getPixel(x, y, new int[3]); // gets the RGB data from the buffer
                    if(pixel[0]< 255 && pixel[1]< 255 && pixel[2]< 255)
                    {    
                        System.out.print(" Y");
                        writefile("Y");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print(" N");
                        writefile("N");
                    }
                }
            System.out.print(" L");
            System.out.println("");
            writefile("L");

            }
            System.out.print("S");
            writefile("S");


        }

    catch (IOException e) // never used it but it needs to be here
    {
    }


}

    public void writefile(String value)
    {
            String array = value; //named it array. i know right :P

            File file = new File(textpath); //path for new file.txt


            try
            {
                if (!file.exists()) // if file doesnt exists, then this will create it ;)
                {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
                try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
                    bw.write(array,0,array.length());
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e) // if IO exceptions happens this outputs Stacktrace
            {

            }



    }

    public void grayscale()
    {
        BufferedImage img = null;


        try
        {
          File f = new File(imgpath); //org pic
          img = ImageIO.read(f);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
          System.out.println(e);
        }





        for(int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++)
            {
            int p = img.getRGB(x,y);

            int a = (p>>24)&0xff;
            int r = (p>>16)&0xff;
            int g = (p>>8)&0xff;
            int b = p&0xff;

            //calculate average
            int avg = (r+g+b)/3;

            //replace RGB value with avg
            p = (a<<24) | (avg<<16) | (avg<<8) | avg;

            img.setRGB(x, y, p);
            }
        }

        try
        {
          File f = new File(graypath); //gray pic
          ImageIO.write(img,imgtype,f);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
          System.out.println(e);
        }
    }



}

I get the error 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.getPixel(ComponentSampleModel.java:750)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.getPixel(Raster.java:1519)
    at grayandconvert.JavaCodeProject.convert(JavaCodeProject.java:41)
    at grayandconvert.JavaCodeProject.main(JavaCodeProject.java:23)
128128C:\Users\clipcomet\Desktop\JavaApplication10\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1051: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\clipcomet\Desktop\JavaApplication10\nbproject\build-impl.xml:805: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

i just started programming a bit ago and i know im using a Lib i dont know fully but needed to use the BufferedImage, ignoring all the bad code i have can someone tell me why i only get that error on some pics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the exception in some cases, is that `Raster.getPixel(x, y, pixel)` tries to copy *all the samples for the pixel* at x, y into the `pixel` array. And you have no control over how many samples per pixel your raster has, if you download random pictures from the net, yet you hardcode the `pixel` array to 3 elements.

From the API doc (emphasis mine):

> `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the coordinates are not in bounds, or *if `iArray` is too small to hold the output*.

Most likely, the images where you get the exception, have 4 components and are RGBA (while the ones from Paint have 3 components, RGB). You will probably get rid of the exception by creating a larger array (ie. `new int[4]`).

However, the best way to fix the problem is to not create the array at all yourself, and instead leave that to the `getPixel` method, like this:

```
int[] pixel = null;
for (y...) {
    for (x...) {
        pixel = raster.getPixel(x, y, pixel);
        ...
    }
}
```

This also ensures that the allocation happens only once, which is obviously good for performance.

---

That said, you still need to handle the fact that a random image may not have the expected number of samples per pixel. If your input is gray or uses a color map (`IndexColoModel`), it will only have one sample (and you'll have an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExpcetion` for your `pixel[1]` and `pixel[2]` array accesses). And for the color map case, the sample values is unrelated to the RGB value you see on screen (it's only an index into a lookup table).

For these reasons, you may find it easier and more intuitive to just use the `BufferedImage.getRGB(x, y)` method, which *always* gives you the ARGB values of the pixel as a single packed int sample, in sRGB color space.